# Released executable still contains classnames, comments and variable names

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I wrote an application in Visual Basic 2010 and when it was finished I wanted to release the application, so I can use it outside of Visual Studio. Of course I already have done this very often, but until now I used the option "Make [application]" of the menu "Debugging". (I think that is correct, I am using the german version of Visual Studio, so I don't know it exactly. But as it says, this is a debuggin-release and it still contains a lot of useless information, that I don't want in a final release.

For example the *.pdb files are generated and the executable still contains the full path of it, names of constant variables, comments, class names, names of local and global variables, method names and many many other information, that I don't want to be there.

Of course I know the option "Project -> Release [application]", but this one generates an useless installer, that requires adminstrator permissions, is very inflexible and not good to use. Moreover, I created a portable application, so why should I release an installer. Finally, I am not sure, wether there are still all those debug information in my executable when I use the installer.

Is there any way to turn of the generation of the debugging information in my executable or export it another way, so it is an 'official' release and ready to share?

Comment: Even with all optimizations turned off and shipping without the debug symbols, your application can be read by every person clever enough to download ilspy, red-gate reflector or jetbrains dotpeek.

Comment: To turn that off, you need to use a tool called an obfuscator. As for the installer, if you created your own, why use the built in click-once installer, indeed.

Comment: Well, an obfuscator is an option, that's right! Thank you for that. I need no installer, because my application is portable and the build-in installer is the biggest rubbish, in my opinion...

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for, is an Obfuscator. There are multiple of these around, there is even one that [ships with Visual Studio as a Community Edition](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/compare-editions). Make sure you get a recent version, the decompilers and the obfuscators constantly being updated to out-smart eachother and some of the older versions offer little security over doing nothing.

[Wikipedia keeps a list of Obfuscators for .NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_obfuscators_for_.NET).